# WCF - Works fine from a console-based app but fails from an asp.net page

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm facing some problems with authentication in my WCF, if I consume the service from a console-based app it works fine but if I try from asp.net then I get:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1126
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +81

[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication    scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10259322
```

I guess I have to configure the IIS where ASP page is hosted, I tried disabling anonymous authentication and enabling Windows Authentication but it does not work.

I'm using BasicHttpBinding and this is my web.config on the server where my WCF is hosted.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>   
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" contract="Contract1"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The ASP.net and console-based config files are the same so I think I should work on the IIS where the service is hosted.

Please let me know if I should post the code or more information about the config files.

Any advice is welcome.

**EDIT**

This is how I consuming the service on the ASP page,

```
    Client client = new Client("BasicBinding");
    try
    {
        string strResult = client.ProcessTransaction(strRequestDetails);
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        lbMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

On the server site, this is the line where the exception is being thrown, notice I isolated the authentication issue in this single line,

```
    public string ProcessTransaction(string strRequestDetails)
    {
        return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
```

Using asp.net 3.5 and IIS 7.5

Comment: Posting both the client and server-side code would be helpful, especially the portion where the exception is being thrown. What version of ASP.NET are you using is also important, Webforms / MVC3, etc.

Comment: @Despertar, take a look to my edition, thanks

Comment: First thing I would check is the identity your AppPool is running as for your ASP.NET site. In IIS, right click the app pool your site is using, go to advanced settings and try changing the identity property to authenticate using a windows account.

Comment: @Despertar, I did it but I got the same error. Thx